# Problem with installing SmartEdit in a custom ycommercewebservices extension and Spartacus

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I want to install SmartEdit to our project. We have no custom yacceleratorstorefront in our project but a custom ycommercewebservices.

I added all extensions (expect ysmarteditmodule) to our extension and run

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames=smarteditaddon -DaddonStorefront.ycommcerwebservices=ourcustomercommercewebservices
```

On `ant clean all` following error appears:

```
   [yjavac] 1. ERROR in some_path_to_the_repo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/ourcustomercommerwebservices/web/addonsrc/smarteditaddon/de/hybris/platform/smarteditaddon/interceptors/beforeview/SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler.java (at line 6)
   [yjavac]     import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.controllers.pages.AbstractPageController;
   [yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.controllers cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 2. ERROR in some_path_to_the_repo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/ourcustomercommerwebservices/web/addonsrc/smarteditaddon/de/hybris/platform/smarteditaddon/interceptors/beforeview/SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler.java (at line 7)
   [yjavac]     import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.interceptors.BeforeViewHandler;
   [yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorstorefrontcommons.interceptors cannot be resolved
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 3. ERROR in some_path_to_the_repo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/ourcustomercommerwebservices/web/addonsrc/smarteditaddon/de/hybris/platform/smarteditaddon/interceptors/beforeview/SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler.java (at line 28)
   [yjavac]     public class SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler implements BeforeViewHandler
   [yjavac]                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] BeforeViewHandler cannot be resolved to a type
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 4. ERROR in some_path_to_the_repo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/ourcustomercommerwebservices/web/addonsrc/smarteditaddon/de/hybris/platform/smarteditaddon/interceptors/beforeview/SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler.java (at line 38)
   [yjavac]     public void beforeView(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final ModelAndView modelAndView)
   [yjavac]                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] The method beforeView(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ModelAndView) of type SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler must override or implement a supertype method
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 5. ERROR in some_path_to_the_repo/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/ourcustomercommerwebservices/web/addonsrc/smarteditaddon/de/hybris/platform/smarteditaddon/interceptors/beforeview/SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler.java (at line 43)
   [yjavac]     final AbstractPageModel page = (AbstractPageModel) modelAndView.getModel().get(AbstractPageController.CMS_PAGE_MODEL);
   [yjavac]                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   [yjavac] AbstractPageController cannot be resolved to a variable
   [yjavac] ----------
   [yjavac] 5 problems (5 errors)

BUILD FAILED
```

I found a similar issue in https://answers.sap.com/questions/12771124/smarteditaddon-hybris-63-not-working.html that is also related to SmartEdit.
The last answer is:

> It seems that the buildcallbacks.xml in my storefront was not up to date. I compared it to the one in yacceleratorstorefront, added the missing parts and then (after additionally adding some missing files), the build was running without problems.

But we don't have a yacceleratorstorefront in our project. So I compared the yacceleratorstorefront/buildcallbacks.xml with our ourcustomercommerwebservices/buildcallbacks.xml but without success.

Do you have some ideas?

Thanks for your help!
Cheers Philipp

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to make it work. I have removed the smarteditaddon from the localextensions.xml and don't run the addon install. It seems that smartedit don't need the smarteditaddon for spartacus…